# Preg_replace simple math problem with solution?

Tags: php, regex, math, preg-replace

I have strings that contain simple math problems 1+10, 2+2, 5-3... I'm wanting to be able to match these math problems and replace them with the solution.

So that: Jimmy turns 5+5 on Friday. is changed to:  Jimmy turns 10 on Friday.

I dont need multiplication or division at this point so i assume its relatively simple however im not classically trained in PHP. I assume i will need a REGEX to match the problem, but im pretty much lost from there.

```
1+10 becomes 11
2+2 becomes 4
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Formulating the appropriate regex?  Doing the calculation?  Substituting the result into the output string?

Comment: Like Oli said, what's the question here exactly?

Comment: You will need to write a regular expression to isolate and capture the two numbers and the operator.  Then you analyze the operator and evaluate the expression (from the captured sections of the regex), and replace the original pattern with the result of evaluating the expression.  As you increase the complexity of the mathematical expressions, the appropriateness of regular expressions to handle them decreases, and you might well end up needing a grammar and lexical analyzer to process the expression, even if you continue to use a regular expression to isolate the mathematical expression.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Technical that's correct, however there already is a parser that can evaluate such mathematical expressions: PHP itself. Just eval it, there is a regex modifier for that. See my answer below.

Comment: @Hakre: interesting - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just "eval" the replacement - but take care, it's eval ([Demo](http://codepad.org/dVkS6O90)):

```
$subject = 'Jimmy turns 5+5 on Friday, Martha 1+10 on Saturday and Petra is 2*2 today.';

$pattern = '~(\d+[*/+-]\d+)~e';
#                          ^^^ e = eval modifier

# Jimmy turns 10 on Friday, Martha 11 on Saturday and Petra is 4 today.
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $subject);
```

Comment: Clever use of eval, but beware of eval D=