# How to make a calculator in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to use PHP to calculate simple algebraic expressions like, `8*(5+1)`, entered via an `<input>` tag by a normal user (which means, **normal notation**: no syntax changes like `Multiply(8, Add(5, 1)))`. Also, it has to show all steps, but that's not hard. The problem, right now, is calculating the value of the expressions.

Note: this is what I thought so far, which is quite inefficient but it's a provisory solution.
Just replace strings where possible: in our example, recognize the string `5+1` and replace it with `6`. Then, loop again, replace `(6)` with `6`, loop again, and replace `8*6` with `48`.
The code for multiplying, for example, should look like this:

```
for ($a=1; $a < 1000; $a++) {
    for ($b=1; $b < 1000; $b++) {
        string_replace($a . '*' . $b, $a*$b, $string);
    }
}
```

Comment: First thoughts that come to mind is using a stack to push operations and them writing down the order of operations rules you use to decide what operations are performed first. That will help you translate them into code.

Comment: google "Djikstra shunting yard" algorithm, or take a look at the evalmath library on phpclasses

Comment: For reference, back ticks on a Mac keyboard are next to the `Z`

Comment: Use a regex for assertion, then just `eval` it. That's what it's for, even though pros like more convoluted approaches, and yes, newbies should generally shy away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preg_replace simple math problem with solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867740/preg-replace-simple-math-problem-with-solution) and [Securely evaluate simple maths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115277/securely-evaluate-simple-maths)

Comment: why replace if you can break the input and add it??

Comment: @BenM They don't seem to be there. Maybe that's because I'm using an Italian keyboard layout?

Comment: @mario Can you post an example?

Comment: Did you check the examples on google? https://www.google.com/search?q=php+calculator

Comment: If you want to do it right, you'll need to parse the expression, and then (for efficiency) convert that infix expression into a prefix or postfix expression, push it to a stack, then calculate as you pop values and operators.

Comment: @mario - it may be a similar question, but the answer on that question is not recommended. The `e` modifier in preg_replace is deprecated. (there are other ways to achieve similar effects, though)

Comment: @SDC: It's deprecated for good reasons. This one ain't. And yes, there are better duplicates. I'm doing a surface search as I don't care much, but OP is allowed to google for more.

Comment: I noticed all of you are suggesting me eval(). I know I can simply use it, but I need to solve the expression step by step, which need more code than just one eval(). I mean: how to split the string and find the first operation to do? I guess, something like a regex, but I'm not really sure of what to do.

Comment: Hmmmm. most of use are recommending __against__ the use of eval

Comment: Consider this at first: you need to parse strings in BODMAS order. (Google it).

Comment: @MarkBaker's Djikstra shunting yard suggestion seems to be among the best algorithms to use, as it doesn't actually need complex regex (which, actually, I don't know very well as a n00b) and is quite easy to implement. Waiting for other answers, satisfying bot the conditions (solve step-by-step, normal notation).

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html to avoid reinventing the wheel, providing a good way of learning how to do this, and a safe parser/evaluator

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1 , just found it and the answer is the same as mine and I got down-voted thanx allot

Comment: @KA_lin - just because an answer gets upvoted/accepted by some users, doesn't make it a good answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depending on your needs, I would suggest looking into the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It's pretty easy to implement, and works quite well.

Here's an example I whipped up a while ago: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/1232629).

Here's the code copy/pasted into one block:

Expression Definitions:

```
class Parenthesis extends TerminalExpression {

    protected $precidence = 7;

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
    }

    public function getPrecidence() {
        return $this->precidence;
    }

    public function isNoOp() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isParenthesis() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isOpen() {
        return $this->value == '(';
    }

}

class Number extends TerminalExpression {

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
        return $this->value;
    }

}

abstract class Operator extends TerminalExpression {

    protected $precidence = 0;
    protected $leftAssoc = true;

    public function getPrecidence() {
        return $this->precidence;
    }

    public function isLeftAssoc() {
        return $this->leftAssoc;
    }

    public function isOperator() {
        return true;
    }

}

class Addition extends Operator {

    protected $precidence = 4;

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
        return $stack->pop()->operate($stack) + $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
    }

}

class Subtraction extends Operator {

    protected $precidence = 4;

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
        $left = $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
        $right = $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
        return $right - $left;
    }

}

class Multiplication extends Operator {

    protected $precidence = 5;

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
        return $stack->pop()->operate($stack) * $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
    }

}

class Division extends Operator {

    protected $precidence = 5;

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
        $left = $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
        $right = $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
        return $right / $left;
    }

}

class Power extends Operator {

    protected $precidence=6;

    public function operate(Stack $stack) {
        $left = $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
        $right = $stack->pop()->operate($stack);
        return pow($right, $left);
    }
}

abstract class TerminalExpression {

    protected $value = '';

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public static function factory($value) {
        if (is_object($value) && $value instanceof TerminalExpression) {
            return $value;
        } elseif (is_numeric($value)) {
            return new Number($value);
        } elseif ($value == '+') {
            return new Addition($value);
        } elseif ($value == '-') {
            return new Subtraction($value);
        } elseif ($value == '*') {
            return new Multiplication($value);
        } elseif ($value == '/') {
            return new Division($value);
        } elseif ($value == '^') {
            return new Power($value);
        } elseif (in_array($value, array('(', ')'))) {
            return new Parenthesis($value);
        }
        throw new Exception('Undefined Value ' . $value);
    }

    abstract public function operate(Stack $stack);

    public function isOperator() {
        return false;
    }

    public function isParenthesis() {
        return false;
    }

    public function isNoOp() {
        return false;
    }

    public function render() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

The stack (really simple implementation):

```
class Stack {

    protected $data = array();

    public function push($element) {
        $this->data[] = $element;
    }

    public function poke() {
        return end($this->data);
    }

    public function pop() {
        return array_pop($this->data);
    }

}
```

And finally, the executor class:

```
class Math {

    protected $variables = array();

    public function evaluate($string) {
        $stack = $this->parse($string);
        return $this->run($stack);
    }

    public function parse($string) {
        $tokens = $this->tokenize($string);
        $output = new Stack();
        $operators = new Stack();
        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            $token = $this->extractVariables($token);
            $expression = TerminalExpression::factory($token);
            if ($expression->isOperator()) {
                $this->parseOperator($expression, $output, $operators);
            } elseif ($expression->isParenthesis()) {
                $this->parseParenthesis($expression, $output, $operators);
            } else {
                $output->push($expression);
            }
        }
        while (($op = $operators->pop())) {
            if ($op->isParenthesis()) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Mismatched Parenthesis');
            }
            $output->push($op);
        }
        return $output;
    }

    public function registerVariable($name, $value) {
        $this->variables[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function run(Stack $stack) {
        while (($operator = $stack->pop()) && $operator->isOperator()) {
            $value = $operator->operate($stack);
            if (!is_null($value)) {
                $stack->push(TerminalExpression::factory($value));
            }
        }
        return $operator ? $operator->render() : $this->render($stack);
    }

    protected function extractVariables($token) {
        if ($token[0] == '$') {
            $key = substr($token, 1);
            return isset($this->variables[$key]) ? $this->variables[$key] : 0;
        }
        return $token;
    }

    protected function render(Stack $stack) {
        $output = '';
        while (($el = $stack->pop())) {
            $output .= $el->render();
        }
        if ($output) {
            return $output;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException('Could not render output');
    }

    protected function parseParenthesis(TerminalExpression $expression, Stack $output, Stack $operators) {
        if ($expression->isOpen()) {
            $operators->push($expression);
        } else {
            $clean = false;
            while (($end = $operators->pop())) {
                if ($end->isParenthesis()) {
                    $clean = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    $output->push($end);
                }
            }
            if (!$clean) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Mismatched Parenthesis');
            }
        }
    }

    protected function parseOperator(TerminalExpression $expression, Stack $output, Stack $operators) {
        $end = $operators->poke();
        if (!$end) {
            $operators->push($expression);
        } elseif ($end->isOperator()) {
            do {
                if ($expression->isLeftAssoc() && $expression->getPrecidence() <= $end->getPrecidence()) {
                    $output->push($operators->pop());
                } elseif (!$expression->isLeftAssoc() && $expression->getPrecidence() < $end->getPrecidence()) {
                    $output->push($operators->pop());
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while (($end = $operators->poke()) && $end->isOperator());
            $operators->push($expression);
        } else {
            $operators->push($expression);
        }
    }

    protected function tokenize($string) {
        $parts = preg_split('((\d+|\+|-|\(|\)|\*|/)|\s+)', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
        return $parts;
    }

}
```

It works by first tokenizing the input (based on word boundary, and tokens). Then, it runs the Shunting Yard algorithm on it to convert the input into a RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) stack. Then, it's just a matter of executing the stack. Here's a quick example:

```
$math = new Math();

$answer = $math->evaluate('(2 + 3) * 4');
var_dump($answer);
// int(20)

$answer = $math->evaluate('1 + 2 * ((3 + 4) * 5 + 6)');
var_dump($answer);
// int(83)

$answer = $math->evaluate('(1 + 2) * (3 + 4) * (5 + 6)');
var_dump($answer);
// int(231)

$math->registerVariable('a', 4);
$answer = $math->evaluate('($a + 3) * 4');
var_dump($answer);
// int(28)

$math->registerVariable('a', 5);
$answer = $math->evaluate('($a + $a) * 4');
var_dump($answer);
// int(40)
```

Now, this example is significantly more complex than you may need. The reason is that it also handles grouping and operator precedence. But it's a decent example of a running algorithm that doesn't use EVAL and supports variables...

Comment: It's perfect for my needs, although it seems to give errors working with variables. Exactly:    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Undefined Value a' in /index.php:122 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(177): TerminalExpression::factory('a') #1 /index.php(167): Math->parse('($a + 3) * 4') #2 /index.php(290): Math->evaluate('($a + 3) * 4') #3 {main} thrown in /index.php on line 122

Comment: I had problems with line breaks, so i made a few unsuccessful edits. Anyway. It misses one of the key features I need, which is solving step-by-step. I could give a try with explode() using parenthesis, but still it's not the solution.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello: I fixed the issues with the tokenizer regex. It'll now handle linebreaks and variables correctly. Just replace the last method of the Math class (as that has the corrected regex)...

Comment: [This lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc) should be mentioned as related material.

Comment: @ircmaxell The code now works perfectly, thanks. Would you like to be cited, or is any attribution required?

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello: Just put the link to the gist in the comments. Other than that, it's completely up to you...

Comment: Okay, thanks. FYI [if you'll ever need it, LOL], power (x^n) doesn't work, but I'm trying to fix it myself.

Comment: Editing, to add power support (just in case somebody needs it).

Comment: @ircmaxell hi i have one doubt may i ask

Answer (score 4):

There is a Math Parser class called [bcParserPHP](http://www.bestcode.com/html/math_parser_for_php.html) that might be of interest.

Seems fairly simple to use and pretty powerful.

Example code from their site:

```
$parser = new MathParser();
$parser->setVariable('X', 5);
$parser->setVariable('Y', 2);
$parser->setExpression('COS(X)+SIN(Y)/2');
echo $parser->getValue();
```

Unfortunately, it's a commercial product; I don't know if that would stop you using it or not (guess it depends on the price and on your needs).

A non-commercial alternative might be this one: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html

Note that this class uses `eval()` internally, which I would avoid doing if possible.

Failing that, writing your own language parser would be the ideal solution, but not really sensible to do that in PHP.

Comment: The use of eval() in evalmath can easily be avoided with a small bit or code reworking to replace it with a whitelisted function set, and the use of call_user_func_array()

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by stripping the input of anything which shouldn't be in the expression (assuming you just want to allow add, subtract, multiply, divide, and no variables):

```
 $expr = preg_replace('/[^0-9+*\/-]/', '', $expr);
```

and then, once I'm confident nothing dangerous remains in the user input, simply pass the itthrough eval() to evaluate the expression:

```
 $result = eval("return $expr;");
```

No need to reinvent the wheel.

**Edited** to incorporate Kolink's corrections. Thanks!

Comment: `eval` doesn't return anything unless there's a `return` statement in it - unlike in JavaScript where the return value is the value of the last expression. Also, don't forget to escape the characters you use as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections -- I've updated the answer. That'll teach me to answer from my phone while I'm out having a smoke...

Comment: Well, that's not a great thing to do, since if there's a syntax error (for example, if I did `0 + 1 1` as input) it'll bork the entire system... Better to use a full fledged parser...