# How to count with an array of operators

Tags: php, foreach, operators, combinations

```
$operators = array(
    "+",
    "-",
    "*",
    "/"
);

foreach($operators as $key => $opp){
    //echo "key: $key, opperator: $opp <br />";
    echo $result = 4 . $opp . 4 . "<br />";
}
```

why isn't my code counting the possible combinations?

like:

```
echo $result = 4 + 4;
```

8

Comment: I think it's because +, -, *, / is here as string, not as operator.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: He wrote - like:
`echo $result = 4 + 4;`

Comment: [How to make a calculator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Comment: Two answers using eval() and neither of them highlight the dangers or problems of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid eval using some anon functions, 5.3+ required

```
$operators = array(
    "+" => function($l,$r) { return $l + $r; },
    "-" => function($l,$r) { return $l - $r; },
    "*" => function($l,$r) { return $l * $r; },
    "/" => function($l,$r) { return $l / $r; },
);

foreach($operators as $key => $opp){
    //echo "key: $key, opperator: $opp <br />";
    echo $result = $opp(4,4). "<br />";
}
```

Comment: This answer brings me the most!

Answer (score 2):

Dot (".") is concatenation operator for strings in PHP. Dynamic typization makes all this a string.
Actually you get same as:

```
echo $result = "4 + 4 <br />";
```

Use eval as said in prev answer.

```
foreach($operators as $key => $opp){
    echo $result = eval("echo 4 $opp 4;") . "<br />"; // eval should contain valid code
}
```

Comment: : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D: eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Sorry) Already edited with valid code. eval can perform only valid one, which simple "4 + 4" isn't.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are just doing something with strings. They're not treated as operators.

You could of course use eval:

```
$x = eval(4 . $opp . 4 );
echo $x;
```