# Convert string into Math equation

Tags: php, math

I'm simply wanting to convert a string which contains an equation into an actual PHP Math Equation, is this possible using PHP5+ ? If so, how?

Here's some examples of which the string may be:

```
$string = "37-0";
$string = "315+10";
$string = "25+50";
$string = "88-13";
```

I simply want to parse these into the correct Mathematical answer if that's possible

Comment: what's problem it will work

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php is n excellent ___and safe___ calculator for math equations without any of the problems and dangers of eval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = '37 - 0';
eval( '$result = (' . $str. ');' );
echo $result;
```

Check the [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

> Evaluates the given code as PHP.

**On a side note:**

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: This solution is the better write up, but I prefer @Valentin Mercier's method (below): it just  requires a final semicolon to work. eg. $result = eval("return " . $string . ";");

Comment: For safety, it would be good to clean the string first, for example $str = preg_replace('/[^0-9+-\/*]+/', '', $str);

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [the PHP function eval](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.eval.php)

Use it like this:

```
$string = "88-13";
$result = eval("return " . $string);
```