# Calculate Dynamic Formula in php and retrieve its value dynaimcally

Tags: php

I am creating payroll system for Indian government employee. I have Some problem in creating dynamic formula and also fetch its result.

Suppose we have basic salary = 5000 and gross salary is 20,000

So gross amount is divided in below category:

```
TA  = 10% of gross
HRA = Basic + gross * 20 /100
TA ON DA = 
CA = TA * 15 / 100
MA = Basic + TA
PPF = Gross * 5 /100
```

I want above categories (TA, DA< HRA) should be dynamic and their formula also should be dynamic and when i fetch the formula, it gave me value according to formula.

Note: I don't want to add more modules for category if there is change in future we could change this or add new more category dynamically

Is this possible or not?

Comment: It's perfectly possible; where are you having problems?

Comment: My problem is in calculation of formula

Comment: I have successfully created formula and inserted in db but when i fetch it how can i calculated the formula ?

Comment: Show the formulas exactly as you retrieve them from the database

Comment: Example Suppose I have create HRA field and create formula like below Basic + gross * 20 /100 and insert in db as string so when i fetch this string how can i calculate formula

Comment: [How to make a calculator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?