# PHP Calculator not working (Repeating of Preg Match)

Tags: php

i have got this preg_match for my calculator

```
"#([0-9.-]+) ([+-/*]+) ([0-9.-]+) \=#si"
```

And it work fine, but i need there option to repeat.
Because this can calculate only -25 + 3 =
but cannot calculate something like this -25 + 3 * 6 / 5 =
I need something, what will repeat this
`([+-/*]+) ([0-9.-]+)` infinitely. Is it possible? If it, how can i do that? Thanks for answers.

Comment: [How to make a Calculator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Comment: look through this for ideas https://github.com/funsholaniyi/html-php-calculator