# Create a calculation formula from form data

Tags: php, forms, calculation

I get from the form field the following information:

Only once the formula for the calculation

```
(z + a * (s-k)) * d + (m * x)
```

And seven text (input) fields with this information:

```
value => 0.5
name => a

value => 10.2
name => z

value => 4
name => x

value => 2
name => s

value => 2
name => d

value => 0.4
name => k

value => 2.1
name => m
```

From this information I would like this result as a text for the calculation:

```
(10.2 + 0.5 * (2-0.4)) * 2+ (2.1 * 4)
```

My experiment looks like this:

```
$sFields => stdClass Object (

    [price] => 0.5
    [letter] => a

    [price] => 10.2
    [letter] => z

    [price] => 4
    [letter] => x

    [price] => 2
    [letter] => s

    [price] => 2
    [letter] => d

    [price] => 0.4
    [letter] => k

    [price] => 2.1
    [letter] => m
)

$sFormula = $this->formRequestParameter("(z + a * (s-k)) * d + (m * x)");

    protected function _calculateFormFields($sFields, $sFormula)
    {

        $formulaString = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", ',', strtolower($sFormula));

        $exLetter = explode(',', $formulaString);

        $sPrice = null;

        foreach ($exLetter as $sKey => $sVal) {

            if (strtolower($sVal) == strtolower($sFields->letter)) {

                $sPrice[$sKey] = $sFields->price;

            }
        }

        $buildFormula = str_replace(

            $exLetter,
            $sPrice,
            $sFormula
        );

        print_r($buildFormula);

        // $this->_calculatePrice($buildFormula);
    }
```

And the output looks like this. :-(

```
10.2 (+*(-))*+(*) 
4 (+*(-))*+(*) 
2.1 (+*(-))*+(*) 
2 (+*(-))*+(*) 
2 (+*(-))*+(*)  
0.5 (+*(-))*+(*)  
0.4 (+*(-))*+(*)
```

Comment: $result = ($_POST['z'] + $_POST['a'] * ($_POST['s']-$_POST['k'])) * $_POST['d'] + ($_POST['m'] * $_POST['x']);

Comment: [How to  make  a calculator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Comment: This is not the calculation. Only letters with the correct numbers are to be exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `letter` is the name of the form fields :

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$z = $_POST['z'];
$x = $_POST['x'];
$s = $_POST['a'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$k = $_POST['k'];
$m = $_POST['m'];

$result = ($z + $a * ($s-$k)) * $d + ($m * $x);
```

Comment: not $_POST['A']; it should be $_POST['a']; you should not capitalize the name fields

Comment: Thank you Ahmad. Calculation formula is variable, see my updated code. That would not work.

Comment: @anonym  you dont want the final results!? do you want the string representing the formula?  what is `$field` and `$formula` variablae?  how do you use the `_calculateFormFields`  function ?

Comment: Ahmad, a calculation function I've already written. I've posted the output, see above. First, the sequence of numbers is not correct and second, all operators are written by numbers.

Comment: @anonym show me `$field` and `$sFormula` , before using them in your function

Answer (score 0):

Get the form data using $_POST method, store them in separate variables and then calculate the result using the formula as shown in here:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$z = $_POST['z'];
$x = $_POST['x'];
$s = $_POST['s'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$k = $_POST['k'];
$m = $_POST['m'];

$result = ($z + $a * ($s-$k)) * $d + ($m * $x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$post_array = ['a' => 0.5,'z' => 10.2,'x' => 4,'s' => 2,'d' => 2,'k' => 0.4,'m' => 2.1]; // $post_array = $_POST; 

extract($post_array); // or extract($_POST)

echo ($z + $a * ($s-$k)) * $d + ($m * $x);
```

Comment: is your post array is as shown in my answer? @anonym

Comment: I have extracted the values to key variable using extract() function