# preg_replace_callback_array Doesn't return match calculation value

Tags: php, function, php-7.2, preg-replace-callback

I try preg_replace_callback_array for math bbcode. Its returning as plain text while i require calculated result

```
<?php
$kode = array (
  "/\[math\]([0-9+\-\/*\)\(]+?)\[\/math\]/" =>
    function($matches) {$value = "$matches[1]"; return $value;},
);
$body = 'my result is [math]100-3[/math]';

echo preg_replace_callback_array($kode,$body);
?>
```

Bbcode work fine but doesn’t return calculation

If i use `[math]100+10[/math]` it return `100+10` but i want to get `110` here

Comment: Can you provide the value of `$kode` in your code?

Comment: its updated on question sir

Comment: You need to write code that parses and executes the mathematical expression. Just using the variable doesn't execute it.

Comment: You could use `eval($matches[1])`, but that's dangerous.

Comment: If you do that, someone could write `[math]unlink("some_important_file");[/math]`

Comment: @Barmar The pattern won't match that :)

Comment: Dupe of [How to make a calculator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php).

Comment: it was work fine on this but /e modifier not support in php7  $kode = array (
"/\[math\]([0-9+\-\/*\)\(]+?)\[\/math\]/e"=>'$1',
);
$body = 'my result is [math]100-3[/math]';

echo preg_replace(array_keys($kode),array_values($kode),$body);

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/NN7eB

Answer (score 1):

This is, in general, difficult. Your evaluation `$value = "$matches[1]"` would simply evaluate the string value. There is no simple function in PHP core library to convert a numerical calculation formula string into the result.

You may, however, learn to install [chriskonnertz/string-calc](https://github.com/chriskonnertz/string-calc) with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and use it.

```php
<?php

use ChrisKonnertz\StringCalc\StringCalc;

$kode = array (
  "/\[math\]([0-9+\-\/*\)\(]+?)\[\/math\]/" => function($matches) {
    $calc = new StringCalc();
    return $calc->calculate($matches[1]);
  },
);
$body = 'my result is [math]100-3[/math]';

echo preg_replace_callback_array($kode,$body);
?>
```

Comment: It was work without composar on 5.6 but on php 7 /e modifier not working    $kode = array (
"/\[math\]([0-9+\-\/*\)\(]+?)\[\/math\]/e"=>'$1',
);
$body = 'my result is [math]100-3[/math]';

echo preg_replace(array_keys($kode),array_values($kode),$body);

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of that. +1.

Comment: The [PCRE modifier `e`](https://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.5.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0. You simply cannot use it anymore in PHP 7+.

Comment: But that would be a neat trick for older versions of PHP. Didn't know about it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `eval()`. This is normally a very dangerous function, but your pattern only matches simple numerical expressions, so it's safe here.

```
$kode = array (
  '/\[math\]([0-9+\-\/*)(]+?)\[\/math\]/' =>
    function($matches) {eval("\$value = $matches[1];"); return $value;},
);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for reply i make it working like this

```
  $kode = array (
  "/\[math\]([0-9+\-\/*\)\(]+?)\[\/math\]/" =>
    function($matches) {$value = "$matches[1]"; return eval('return ' . $value . ';');},
);
$body = 'my result is [math]100-3[/math]';

echo preg_replace_callback_array($kode,$body);
```